# Group theory and its connection with Galois Theory

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

In our project we are asked to do some work on “**Group Theory and its connection with Galois Theory**” and I have no idea of punching these two in a single format. How can I do these? Any kind of suggested outline would be appreciated.

Comment: How much background do you have in group theory and Galois theory?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've studied Group Theory and Galois Theory thoroughly. I'm just having problems with the format of the final project work.

Comment: There are many possible topics. For example, prove theorems on the Galois group of polynomials. Construct a polynomial of degree $p$ for every prime $p$, having Galois group $S_p$. Determine all possible Galois groups of quintics and higher degree polynomials.

Comment: Galois theory has more to do with field theory, it focus on structures and their extension ( sub group )

Comment: You could take a theorem from group theory and see what it says about Galois groups of field extensions: for example any group of order $p^2$ for $p$ a prime is abelian, so any galois extension of degree $p^2$ has abelian Galois group, and you should be able to say a lot about what those extensions look like.

Answer (score 2):

Galois theory is basically about attaching certain groups to certain Field extensions. So if you start reading about Galois theory, group theory will naturally come into the picture. You don't have to go looking for a connection separately.

A good reference for Galois theory is the book by Rotman

Comment: Thanks Krishnarjun for your kind reply. That's my project work and I'm not sure how to put those into the same document. I mean should I go with the group theory art and the necessary theorems of group theory which are used in Galois theory and then start listing those Galois theory related theorems or what. I hope I've managed to make you understand.

Comment: Personally, I would think that writing about Galois theory itself has enough elements of group theory in it. But again that is how I would do it.

Comment: Okay. I will have a look at Rotman's book and see if it helps. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Permutation groups found its origin in the study of the roots of polynomial equations. This is what Galois discovered and developed. The [book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=C9_Vivwgf5cC&pg=PA1&hl=nl&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Ian Stewart, *Galois Theory*, with nice historical notes might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact Group theory was originated in the hand of [Evariste Galois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89variste_Galois) in order to solve polynomials of degree $5$ or more, over a field. He basically used the radicals over some extensions of the base field and formed permutation group. In this  way Group theory generated in a parallel way of Galois theory.